# How to connect to a webserver hosted on vmplayer guest os?

Tags: linux, windows, networking, vmware, vmware-player

I am running a webserver (eg: tomcat7) in vmplayer guest, with NAT and I am able to view the webserver from guest using it's hostname:port but host browser is unable to connect to this webserver. Any idea? Is there any specific network configuration that needs to be done for host to connect to guest?

Note: I used ifconfig and got ip address from eth8, but ping request times out all the time.

VMWARE player network settings screenshot

[image]

**Update**
I also had to add entries in both machines hosts file for DNS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the network settings to use Bridged. That will connect to your router and get an IP off DHCP which your Host will be able to see. NAT is using your host address.